# Remote Debugging DataProc PySpark Job

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Is there any way to debug PySpark job on DataProc remotely?

As DataProc Spark is running in yarn cluster, it is not exposing tcp connection, so for example how can submit and debug job by IDE remotely?

-- Update:

By PyCharm to submit job and access SparkContext to debug the job code. I see this [guide](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/15030/spark-remote-debugging.html) for java, but I am not sure such thing is possible on DatProc or not.

Comment: How remotely and any specific IDE? For example, what about a notebook running on the cluster itself you can HTTP into?

Comment: You may consider using [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/) for debugging, it will require some configuration though.